# Windows Service is not logging actions

Tags: c#, service

What Im actualy trying to do is to create a windows service, that will be listening to one exact IP adress and port and after receiving message write information to the file.

Here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;

namespace Active_service
{
    public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
    {
        const int port = 8005;
        static TcpListener listener;
        public Service1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.CanStop = true;
            this.CanPauseAndContinue = true;
            this.AutoLog = true;
            File.AppendAllText("Log.txt","\n Initialized" + " " + DateTime.Now.ToString());
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            File.AppendAllText("Log.txt","\n Started!");
            Thread listen_thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Listen));
            listen_thread.Start();
        }

        public void Listen()
        {
            IPEndPoint ipPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"),port);
            Socket listen_socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            
            try
            {
                listen_socket.Bind(ipPoint);
                listen_socket.Listen(10);
                File.AppendAllText("Log.txt", "\n Listening!");

                while (true)
                {
                    Socket handler = listen_socket.Accept();
                    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                    int bytes = 0;
                    byte[] data = new byte[256];
                    do
                    {
                        bytes = handler.Receive(data);
                        builder.Append(Encoding.Unicode.GetString(data, 0, bytes));
                    }
                    while (handler.Available > 0);
                    File.AppendAllText("Log.txt","\n Message received:" + builder.ToString());
                    handler.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                    handler.Close();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                File.AppendAllText("Log.txt","\n " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            File.AppendAllText("Log.txt", "Stopped!");
        }
        protected override void OnPause()
        {
            base.OnPause();
        }
        protected override void OnContinue()
        {
            base.OnContinue();
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is: When I'm compiling code, line "\n Initialized!" is added to the file, but after I'm setting up the service it's accepting TPC communication (no error throwed after I'm sending message from other software), but nothing is added to "Log.txt", even "Initialized" message.
What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Please for love of all microsoft gods ... use a Logging Framework.

Comment: That's just an example of action, done by the service after it's receiving the message using TCP, but thanks, I'll thy it!

Comment: But aside that, where are you looking for it? I suspect you are looking at the wrong file.

Comment: Actualy, I thought about it, but I'm looking into the file, that are in the debug folder of the project, right close to *.exe file, am I stupid?

Comment: Well, while debugging it, that's correct. If you run that as a service however, it will be created in whatever folder is considered the "current folder" ... definitely not in .../bin/debug :)

Comment: You can try to specify an absolute path like "C:\temp\Log.txt" ("C:\temp" must exist) But just to prove that point. I still _highly recommend_ using a logging framework instead.

Comment: Aaaaannd.... You were 100% correct - it created the file in directory: C:\Windows\SysWOW64 . Thank you! For logging framework advice as well!

Comment: De nada. We've all been there, once.

Comment: I am actually surprised, the system let your service create a file there. I would have expected a "Not Authorized" Exception. Maybe "check your privileges" ;) It shouldn't run as Admin.